# Return the only value from a range that contains one populated cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm new to Excel.  I have a Laser measurer recording results in a spreadsheet:

- Each row in `D:G` contains a single populated column and the remaining columns are empty.
- The column that is populated varies by row.

I have formula that converts the value to a string listing feet and inches.

For example, in row `10` where the value is in column `F`, my formula is:

```
=INT(F10/12)&"' "&MOD(F10,12)&"""
```

This formula works but I have to know the column number in advance.

I want to adapt the formula to work for all rows regardless which column is actually populated.

[image: image showing functionality]

Answer (score 2):

Your description is not entirely clear. Assuming you have really empty cells and only one numerical value in your range, you can adapt the following pragmatic solution for your purposes:

```
=INT(SUM(A2:D2)/12)&"' "&MOD(SUM(A2:D2);12)&""""
```

Please note the screenshot is from an German Excel 2019 version. You must at least replace the semicolon with a comma.

```
=INT(SUM(A2:D2)/12)&"' "&MOD(SUM(A2:D2),12)&""""
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I wanted!!!

Comment: @Billibong13 You're welcome. If an answer has helped you solve your problem feel free to mark the answer as accepted. You should also consider voting it up

Answer (score 2):

[@P.b's single-row formula is great!](https://superuser.com/a/1815311/). Below is an array formula approach that leverages it but uses [BYROW](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/byrow-function-2e04c677-78c8-4e6b-8c10-a4602f2602bb) to extend it to multiple rows.  It is no better than their [MMULT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mmult-function-40593ed7-a3cd-4b6b-b9a3-e4ad3c7245eb) array formula, I simply enjoy making formulas as short as possible.

## Formula

```
=BYROW(D14:G16, LAMBDA(r, TEXT(SUM(r)/1.2, "#0' 0''")))
```

Answer (score 1):

`=TEXT(SUM(D14:G14)/1.2,"#0' 0''")`

Or spilling in Office 365:

```
=LET(f,D14:G16,
     TEXT(MMULT((f/1.2),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(f),,,0)),"#0' 0''"))
```

Comment: @BlindSpots It's alright. BYROW is nice too. I'm a big fan of MMULT. If you're looking for short: `tocol(column(f)^0)` I believe the step 0 argument in the sequence calculates more efficient, but for this anything suits.

Comment: Even better!  TY! I upvoted you but someone's downvote put you at 0  maybe because of the typo.  Hopefully, they will reverse their vote now that it's corrected.

Comment: Thanks for the positive feedback